# Sum Column Based on Other Columns with Similar Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to write a SQL query that would sum values based on another columns data. The part that have me stomped is the fact that the other column's data is partially alike as seen below.

```
  AccountID        AcctName       Amount
  ---------------------------------------
  1-1-100-2        Vehicles       10000
  1-1-100-3        Vehicles       20000
  1-1-100-4        Vehicles       20000
  1-2-500-1        Books          10000
  1-2-600-1        Pencils         500
```

I'd like to have this data display as:

```
  AccountID        AcctName       Amount
  --------------------------------------
  1-1-100          Vehicles       50000
  1-2-500          Books          10000
  1-2-600          Pencils         500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the significant part of `AccountId` is always the first 7 characters, you can try with:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(AccountID,0,7),
    AcctName,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY AcctName, SUBSTRING(AccountID,0,7)
```

Comment: Thanks alot.  This was the answer, I managed to get most of it just wasn't including the substring in the GROUP BY clause like this.

Answer (score 1):

Group by AcctName, left(AccountID, 7)